# Invoicing api service

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to create the following environment:

Some users will create some features in my website and for each task they will receive some money.

When the user reaches certain quantity of money the user is allowed to click a button to request the money to my paypal account. Then, programmatically, a invoice will be created in ours paypal accounts and my business account would  pay the debt.

The question is that I could only achieve this scenario using two business account (so the user of my website has to be a business account) because it was the only way to have API credentials for creating a invoice in the user account.(my php code is doing this)

But I wanted to achieve the scenario above using a normal account so that the user would be able to create a invoice that would be available in ours paypal accounts and my business account would pay the invoice for my user that requested the payment.

Is it possible achieve the same using a 'normal' account? If not, is there other option besides invoicing for having this done?

Comment: For actual invoicing they will need to be a business account.  You don't need to setup an invoice to pay them, though.  You could just use the Pay API to send them money directly and that would work with personal or business accounts.

Comment: Hi, Andrew! Thanks for the comment. That's true, in fact I can do this with paypal as you said! But it will be almost impossible to handle manually with lots of money requests and the system I am developing is for a big company [actually a start up with a bold and innovative solution] (so a lot of transactions) the invoice api would come to help us for making this process easier! =)

Comment: I guess I'm not following.  You wouldn't have to do anything manually.  It could all be automated via the API.  If you're just sending a payment to somebody there is no need to use invoicing at all.

Comment: Andrew, it is because one of the requirements is that everything should be done using paypal. So the payment request has to be made by the user with paypal account - and it has to be audited in the paypal account with a invoice so that our business account should pay. It is because of the requirement =/